# Does BasicHttpClientConnectionManager has to be closed after it was used?

Tags: spring, spring-boot

Per definition BasicHttpClientConnectionManager can maintains only one active connection. If several request has to be handled at the same time each request require a new instance of BasicHttpClientConnectionManager. does after each request BasicHttpClientConnectionManager.close() has to be called?

```
        final HttpComponentsClientHttpRequestFactory factory = new HttpComponentsClientHttpRequestFactory();
        BasicHttpClientConnectionManager connManager = new BasicHttpClientConnectionManager();
        connManager.setConnectionConfig(ConnectionConfig.custom().build());
        factory.setHttpClient(HttpClients.custom()
                                         .setConnectionManager(connManager)
                                             .build());
        RestTemplate resttemplate = new RestTemplate(factory);
        resttemplate.execute(...);
        connManager.close();
```